Blenderbot: Key error while training from json
I am trying to train the blenderbot model facebook/blenderbot-90m on a set of questionnaire based on my input json.
The Sample json (snippet) looks like this:
[
  {
    "input": "Who is Carole Nicholas?",
    "output": "She is a software engineer !"
  },
  {
    "input": "Where was Carole Nicholas born?",
    "output": "She was born in San Franscisco."
  },
  {
    "input": "Which was Carole's school?",
    "output": "Lake Side school."
  },
  {
    "input": "Where is Lakeside school located?",
    "output": "It is located at Seattle!"
  }
]

Code for training:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, DataCollatorWithPadding
from datasets import Dataset
import torch

modelName = "facebook/blenderbot-90m"

# Load the dataset
dataset = Dataset.from_json("C:\\Users\\Raj\\Desktop\\To-Dos\\AI_related\\chatInput.json")

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(modelName)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelName)

# Preprocess the data
def preprocess(examples):
    model_inputs = tokenizer(
        examples["input"],
        examples["output"],
        padding="max_length",
        truncation=True,
        max_length=512,
    )
    return model_inputs

dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, batched=True)
#print(dataset['input'])

train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.8)
val_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.1)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size - val_size

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class BlenderBotDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset, tokenizer):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        encoding = self.dataset[idx]
        return {
            "input_ids": torch.tensor(encoding["input_ids"]),
            "attention_mask": torch.tensor(encoding["attention_mask"]),
            "labels": torch.tensor(encoding["input_ids"]),
        }


from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataset = BlenderBotDataset(dataset[train_size], tokenizer)
val_dataset = BlenderBotDataset(dataset[val_size], tokenizer)


train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=False)

from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

# Define the training arguments
#training_args = TrainingArguments("test-trainer")

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="C:\\Users\\Raj\\Desktop\\To-Dos\\AI_related",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    save_total_limit=2,
    save_steps=500,
    #load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
    greater_is_better=True,
    save_on_each_node=True
)

print(dataset[train_size])

# Create the trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    #tokenizer = tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator
    #compute_metrics=lambda pred: {"accuracy": torch.sum(torch.argmax(pred.label_ids, dim=1) == torch.argmax(pred.predictions, dim=1)) / len(pred.label_ids)},
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()

Gives this error:
0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\TrainChatbot.py", line 99, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2164, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2473, in _inner_training_loop
    batch_samples, num_items_in_batch = self.get_batch_samples(epoch_iterator, num_batches)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 5130, in get_batch_samples
    batch_samples += [next(epoch_iterator)]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\data_loader.py", line 452, in __iter__
    current_batch = next(dataloader_iter)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 701, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 757, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Raj\PycharmProjects\PythonProject\TrainChatbot.py", line 45, in __getitem__
    encoding = self.dataset[idx]
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 2
  0%|          | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Process finished with exit code 1

